# Redis GUI needed for AWS ElastiCache on an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I've a AWS ElastiCache Redis cluster setup that I wish to manage. Since AWS doesn't let you access ElastiCache outside the VPC, I've setup a micro EC2 instance that carried a copy of the phpRedisAdmin script pointed to this cluster. But AWS has disabled the 'CONFIG' command on the Redis cluster so phpRedisAdmin can't connect and manage the ElastiCache cluster.

I've tried the redis-browser node package but it runs on 0.0.0.0:4567 and I'll need a public IP on this instance to manage the Redis cluster.

Any sugggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to give a try to [**Redsmin**](https://redsmin.com).

### If you have an EC2 instance in the same subnet as your Redis ElasticCache

Note:

- This will only work if the EC2 instance you connect to **is in the same subnet** as your ElasticCache Redis instance.
- The following example will state that your ElastiCache private IP is `172.31.5.13` and is running on port `6379`.
- The following example will state that your EC2 private IP is `172.31.5.14` and its public IP is `52.50.145.87`.

Now let's do this step by step:

- Connect to this EC2 instance through SSH
- run `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6379 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.31.5.13:6379` don't forget to change your IPs and maybe even the port number
- run `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 172.31.5.13 --dport 6379 -j SNAT --to-source 172.31.5.14`
- run `sudo service iptables save`
- **if** the previous command **did not work**, try:

  - on Debian/Ubuntu => `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4`
  - on RHEL/CentOS => `iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables`
- Add a rule in the security group to allow inbound request from Redsmin IP `62.210.222.165`, protocol=TCP, port=6379
- Add a new Direct Server in redsmin with the connection string: `redis://52.50.145.87:6379`, done!

### If you don't have an EC2 instance in the same subnet as your Redis ElasticCache

- Follow this amazon tutorial to [setup a NAT instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Access.Outside.html), setup it **on the same subnet as your ElastiCache** server.
- Now follow the previous section above.

### If you simply want to connect Redsmin to an EC2 Redis

- Add a rule in the security group to allow inbound request from Redsmin IP `62.210.222.165` (don't forget to specify the right port, for instance `6379`)
- Connect your Redis server in Redsmin using the EC2 public IP and the port you opened.

Comment: the link to `setup a nat instance` doesn't say anything on setting up a nat instance, do you have any other link/info related to this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the `ElastiCache private IP` by pinging the Primary Endpoint from the EC2 shell.

```
PING xyz.abc.euw2.cache.amazonaws.com (172.31.xxx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old post, but it came up in my search and the accepted method did not work for me.

I am posting what worked for me in case someone else will need it:

I used [MobaXTerm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) [Tunnels function](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/documentation.html#2_1_5) to connect to EC2 Amazon Linux instance using local port 6379.  The Tunnels dialog is very user-friendly and easy to use.